# Can a Surge Travel on a Residential House's Wiring that is higher than 6kV and 3kA?

Tags: wiring, surge-protection, lightning

IEEE has stated that the highest voltage and amperage that a surge can travel on home wiring is 6kV and 3kA.  Anything higher, the wiring would melt.

If this is so, how does a surge from direct or indirect lightning travel through home wiring and literally blow up electrical equipment?

I don't get it.

Comment: I’ve sputtered copper over a meter and vaporized a fat blade screwdriver tip removing a staple with same. Copper spray melted into my safety glasses.. could be higher current at 120 V

Comment: Lightning can induce or inject about any voltage or current it wishes into anything it's heart may desire. Even if a switchboard is a heap of molten slag then [arcs as big as The Round Tower](https://andersen.sdu.dk/vaerk/hersholt/TheTinderBox_e.html) can be available to convey current to wheresoever Murphy may desire it to be conveyed to. | Even  an 11 kV line dropped onto a residential 230 VAC feed will make wall mounted home appliances leap off the wall (based on real world accounts here a few decades back).

Comment: I doubt that's what the IEEE really says. More likely they say, that is the highest current and voltage that it is worth protecting against. Either because the statistics of surges mean larger surges are vanishingly unlikely, or because larger surges mean you have bigger problems than protecting your TV and hairdrier.

Answer (score 1):

> If this is so, how does a surge from direct or indirect lightning travel through home wiring and literally blow up electrical equipment?

I don't think that is true, but it doesn't matter.  It doesn't take 30A, let alone 3000A to blow up most home electrical equipment.  Lots of surges will have high enough to burn up electronics on the circuit but be far too small to vaporize the wiring.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning can induce or inject about any voltage or current it wishes into anything it's heart may desire.

Even if a switchboard is a heap of molten slag then [arcs as big as The Round Tower](https://andersen.sdu.dk/vaerk/hersholt/TheTinderBox_e.html) can be available to convey current to wheresoever Murphy may desire it to be conveyed to.

Even  an 11 kV line dropped onto a residential 230 VAC feed will make wall mounted home appliances leap off the wall (based on real world accounts here a few decades back)*.

---

- It was actually a telephone line and telephones - but 11 kV arc flash is no respecter of equipment type.